# Multi column list jquery

Tags: jquery, html, list

I have a list with an unknown amount of items. 
Is there a way with jquery or javascript so the list will be split into columns? 
the tricky part: the count of columns is also dynamic, so when the browser changes it's with, the count of columns changes to. 
You could compare it with floats. So when you make your browser smaller, the floated div will float do the bottum. (if you haven't set a width)
I could have said counted the amount of items and placed them in columns and then float the ul lists. But than you have the problem that it the last column will be placed under the first one. but I would want the "second" column under the first.

for example:

```
<ul>
   <li>test1</li>
   <li>test2</li>
   <li>test2</li>
   <li>test4</li>
   <li>test5</li>
   <li>test6</li>
</ul>
```

If I do a float you will have this:

test1   test2   test3    test4    test5   test6

When the browser gets smaller you have this: 
test1   test2   test3    test4    test5
test6

and it should be:
test1   test3    test4   test5    test6
test2

(this is when you work with floats) so is there a way to change the floating order, or just with jquery to make the columns dynamically?

---

I found this solution, but It's still won't work like I want to. It's the jquery plugin: columnizeList. The list is shown in a few columns but I still  have this problem: 
When I load the page I have for example this list in my div:

[image]

(so It's the same problem as before). I still used float, so maybe that's the problem. But could I solve this without the float?

Comment: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlists/

Comment: Thanks for looking in to this. I also found the website you mentioned, but here I have the same problem. First with the floating, the items are shown next to each other instead of below each other. than you have the choice to use a specific amount of columns. But here that's the problem. So the amount of columns should change with the browser width.

Answer (score 0):

that's how floating works, if you want items to be  shown below each other, you can wrap some of them and then float their wrapper:

```
<ul>
   <div>
     <li>test1</li>
     <li>test2</li>
     <li>test2</li>
     <li>test4</li>
     <li>test5</li>
   </div>
   <div>
     <li>test6</li>         
     <li>test7</li>         
     <li>test8</li>
   </div>
</ul>


ul div {
   float: left
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f8Kgj/

Comment: here you have the same problem with the floating. for example if you have another <div><li>test9</li><li>test10</li></div> those will be placed below the test1, test2, test3,... instead of the test6 that should be below the test5 and the test9 should be shown nest to test1. So because I thought that floating wasn't the best solution, I hoped jquery would be the answer. But I still haven't a solution for that either.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use CSS: `display: flex` and play around with it. You also can make use of [Bootstrap - Flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/) to simplify the changes.

The best thing about flex is you are allowed to re-order the elements simply by type `order: 1` in the styling sheet, and if you use Bootstrap, you can simply put `.order-1` class on first element.

You can also re-order based on screen-width using Bootstrap using `.order-lg-1` class.